# Redirecionar tudo para index.php HTACCESS

Tags: php, htaccess

tenho um site que redireciono tudo para a index.php usando o htaccess
usando esse codigo

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

e a partir da index eu pego o valor passado pela URL e uso a função explode para separa tudo pela barra e valido os dados e redirecinado para as paginas ate tudo bem sò que não consigo recebe dados pelo Get dessa forma

```
http://www.site.com/autos-e-pecas/?val_min=&val_max=
```

quando dou echo na URL vem da seguinte forma

```
http://www.site.com/autos-e-pecas/
```

e não consigo pega os dados acho que se deve pelo redirecionamento la no htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi bem o problema, não sei como esta tentando pegar o GET, mas creio que falta a flag `[QSA]`, ficando assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: era exatamente o que faltava